# MySQL remove everything after n words in column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with over 5000 entries, and basically I want to replace the texts with excerpts. So the column 'text' has between 1000 and 2000 words, most of the time. I want every cell to be cut after 80 words. Additionally it would be nice to add something like 'Read more...' after the 80 words. Is it possible with a MySQL Query?

Comment: If you cut the data in database, how you read when you click read more ? Basically do in your front end code, to display these characters and read more shows fully. If you really want, its possible with sql to cut the data, create a column to save the first 80 characters and update the column with the substring of the actual data in 80 characters

Comment: I would add Read more as an hyperlink to an external site. The hyperlink is saved in an other column... I want to cut it in the database so I don't have an unneccessary big database. Could you help me with the actual query ?

Comment: yes updated as answer

Comment: You might want to look at the extractValue function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html) and parse with xpath;  these kinds of things are regularly handled in RSS feeds,

Answer (score 1):

This is bad idea to do that from MySQL level. This is about the VIEW Layer, so should be programmed in the place which read the data from the database and presents them.
In PHP, it can be done with

```
function cutStringAfterWords($phrase,$max_words){
    $phrase_array = explode(' ',$phrase);
    if(count($phrase_array) > $max_words && $max_words > 0)
        $phrase = implode(' ',array_slice($phrase_array, 0, $max_words)).'...';
    return $phrase;
}

echo cutStringAfterWords($largeText,80).' Read more...';
```

, but I believe most of the languages have their equivalents.

Edit: made an example to cut after 80 words. you can simply replace 3 dots within function to place Read more always, or remove 3 dots in function, and manually add 'Read More...' string after every truncated text

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regex.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_column_name,'(.+?\\s+|.+?){1,80}')
from your_table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nice [MySQL string function SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) which you can use like this to get the result you want:

UPDATE your_table SET your_text_field = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_text_field, ' ', 80) FROM your_table WHERE text_id = some_id) WHERE text_id = some_id;

To add 'Read More..' you can use [MySQL CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Also, I would suggest backing up your table before you start experimenting.

Answer (score -1):

execute below query to update all records with first 80 characters

```
update your_table_name set column_name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, ' ', 80)
```

Updated with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` since you need words

Comment: OP is not asking to literally cut out the text in the database... he wants to take the first 80, and show it

Comment: @Nerd OP isn't clear in his question, but explains in comment that he is trying to reduce the table size and move the full text remotely.

Comment: Ah, yes I see his comment now